# Fetching data into local table type

Tags: sql, oracle, select, stored-procedures

Overall, I need to call a function that takes table type as an argument. I need to fill it up before calling, and that's where I have problem.

The types are defined as follows:

```
create or replace TYPE MY_OBJ IS OBJECT(field1 NUMBER(10), field2 NUMBER(10), field3 VARCHAR2(2));
create or replace TYPE "MY_OBJ_ARRAY_TYPE" IS TABLE OF MY_OBJ;
```

My procedure follows:

```
DECLARE
  -- ...
  v_temp_table MY_OBJ_ARRAY_TYPE;
  -- ...
BEGIN
  v_temp_table := MY_OBJ_ARRAY_TYPE();

  -- the following is incorrect
  SELECT field1, field2, field3
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_temp_table
    FROM table1;

  -- ... call the function here with v_temp_table as parameter
END;
```

The SELECT INTO approach:

```
SELECT INTO TABLE(v_temp_table) (field1, field2, field3)
    VALUES (f1, f2, f3)
    FROM table1;
```

I am not sure what the correct syntax should be, the `v_temp_table` is not being recognized as a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  SELECT NEW MY_OBJ( field1, field2, field3)
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_temp_table
    FROM table1;
```